# Variables in argument doesn't seems to be replaced with the value from the library

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In azure devops I am trying to figure out how to build a release pipeline to release a static website to firebase cloud. I found [this guide](https://medium.com/@dneimke/deploy-to-firebase-from-vsts-3b58430b6379) to help me with that.

I added 2 variables in the library in a variable group with the names 'firebase_token' and 'projectId' I try to use these variables in a release pipeline with one task which executes a powershell script from my repository. I do that via the next argument:

```
-fireBaseToken $(firebase_token) -fireBaseProject $(projectId) -releaseMessage $(Release.ReleaseName)
```

When I try to execute the release pipeline I get an error when the powershell script is being called. This is the error I get

> firebase_token : The term 'firebase_token' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.

When I look at the command that has been tried to execute, I see this:

> Formatted command: . 'D:\a\r1\a\test-project\drop\deploy.ps1' -fireBaseToken $(firebase_token) -fireBaseProject $(projectId) -releaseMessage Release-3

As far as I can see and think of, for some reason $(firebase_token) and $(projectId) aren't replaced by their values.

In my guess that thesee variables should be replaced by there values, what am I doing wrong? What is causing the issue that these variables aren't replaced?

Comment: Did you link the variable group into the release definition?

Comment: No, I did not appearently. I couldn't find any instructions or hints in the article that I had to. So your question triggered me to search again and I found another article which also didn't point me directly in the right way. Then I discovered I overlooked the variable groups option under the variables in the release pipeline and there I can connect the variable groups over there. When I did and I kicked off my release pipeline again, worked. So thank you for helping me searching in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the variable group into your release definition. Simply creating a variable group isn't enough.